# Noughty Mathematics Question

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

Use your imagination to follow these instructions:

---

1. Take out an imaginary piece of paper.
2. Turn it 90° clockwise.
3. Make a mental note to use right-justification and nice, tight [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) and [leading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading).
4. In the top-right corner, draw two zeros.
5. Under that, draw another zero.
6. Under that, draw another zero.
7. Under that, draw two more zeros.
8. Under that, draw yet another zero.
9. Now draw a line underneath,
   —
   as for addition.
10. 

---

Now tell me:

> How many zeros will you have?

Comment: Noughty... I get it... nice

Comment: Is step 10 missing?

Comment: @ubadub Yes. It's part of the puzzle. "What goes in step #10?" :)

Comment: If filling in step 10 is part of the puzzle, then shouldn't it say, "Now tell me: What is step 10 and how many zeros will you have?"

Comment: @jpmc26 I don't believe so. There's a fine line between offering too much information (too easy, no fun!) and offering too little information (too hard, no fun!). I estimated that having step #10 blank and letting the puzzlers figure out what to do with the blank step would add slightly to the difficulty and, perhaps, add a little more fun to the puzzle while keeping it solvable. The question was not "What is step 10, etc.", it was "How many zeros? Use whatever means you find necessary to figure this out." I certainly would've accepted a correct answer that did not specify what step 10 was.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The answer is:

> One hundred zeroes.

As:

> Step 2 is rotating a blank piece of paper. Once the other steps through to step 9 are followed, the paper is still 'on its side'. By recognising the word on its side, the meaning of the blank step 10 becomes clear: 'turn the imaginary paper 90° back again, so that it is right-side up'

Resulting in:

> [image: My awesome drawing]
>  and https://www.google.nl/search?q=googol

Comment: That's it! I'll add the ✅ eventually.

Comment: ah i was seeing Bs not Gs

Comment: I thought the same at first, but that's accounted for in the first part of step 3 in the question: "...use right-justification..."

Comment: I don't understand how you got that from a blank step 10, nor what "as for addition" means in step 9

Comment: This answer assumes [keming](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/290082/72565) rather than kerning.

Comment: @AHKieran If you see BGs then you have a 99% chance of staying alive.

Comment: I don't get it. Where did you get Step 10 from? It's blank in the question.

Comment: @EJacobs and ubadub: Step 2 is rotating a blank piece of paper. That by itself is meaningless. Once you've followed the steps through to step 9, the paper is still 'on its side', and the meaning of the blank step 10 becomes apparent when you recognise the word in the image (on its side).

Answer (score 46):

I [can't see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_impairment) any pattern in the given list of zeroes, so maybe the answer is

> One.

That would be because the paper being imaginary suggests that

> we might very well be on the [complex plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane)

and then the line underneath the zeroes suggests

> that a [complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate) was taken. On the complex plane, this operation mirrors any patterns vertically, which is why the line is now at the bottom.

With this in mind, we can split the zeroes into groups of three lines,

> which will, when vertically mirrored, look a bit like this: **⠼⠚**

which happens to be

> [Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille) for "zero".

<sup><sub>(No. That's not at all far fetched! Why do you keep saying that? Well, maybe it is, just a little. But look! Look! The lateral-thinking tag *is* there!)</sub></sup>

Comment: Has anyone said "Wow!" yet?

Comment: @Chowzen I'll gladly do. Wow!

Comment: @Bass Wow! Wow! Wow!

Comment: If there has ever been a more surprising fitting unintended answer to a puzzle, I don't know what it is.

Comment: @IanMacDonald, I ...may have taken a liberty (or two) in hiding all the cherry picking and shoehorning that was required to make this answer fit at all. But at the first glance, it does seem pretty credible, doesn't it :-)

Answer (score 20):

The answer is:

> Three

Because:

> When you turn the paper back 90 degrees anticlockwise, your drawing looks like:
>  $8^{00}8^01$ (for want of better formatting)
>  Which contains 3 zeroes.
>  It also contains $8008$ which looks like the word **BOOB**, hence the *Noughty/Naughty* pun in the title.

Comment: So you imagined drawing zeros of differing shapes and sizes, depending on how many were on a particular line? (scribbles notes in his psychiatrist's notepad)

Comment: Well I didn't know how to format it...

Comment: So far, this is the closest to the intended answer. And yet, the number "3" is *way* off. :)

Answer (score 18):

The answer is:

> Zero - because the piece of paper is imaginary, and so therefore are the 'drawn' zeroes.

Answer (score 9):

As it says addition:

> [image]

in text:

> **Addition of:** 
> 0 0
>    0
>    0
> 0 0
>    0
>
> ---
>
> 0 0

So there are total of

> 9 zeroes

Comment: I don't see any [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) here...

Comment: @Chowzen.. I thought you meant kerning to align single zeroes to the right, just like we do in addition

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the question answers itself.

> I have drawn seven 0's and then there is three more hole-punched at the bottom of my sheet of paper. So after step nine has me draw something that is not a zero the question answers itself by telling me, there you go, you have ten 0's. 
>  
>  I believe this answer to this question is quite noughty indeed.